# getSpans for Spanned String returns spans out of order?

Tags: android, html, string, arraylist, spanned

I use the following code to sift through a Spanned String saving all bold text as a string in an array:

```
StyleSpan[] spans = storyText.getSpans(0,
        storyText.length(), StyleSpan.class);
List<String> boldedWords = new ArrayList<String>();
for (StyleSpan span : spans) {
    if (span.getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD) {
        //start
        int s = storyText
                .getSpanStart(span);
        //end
        int e = storyText.getSpanEnd(span);
        boldedWords.add(storyText.subSequence(
                s, e).toString());
    }
}

String[] array = boldedWords
        .toArray(new String[boldedWords.size()]);
```

However, the Strings I receive back in the array are out of order. For example:

Sentence might be (CAPS represent bold text):

```
storyText = "This ADJECTIVE NOUN is VERB"
```

The array I'd get back would be: "Noun, Verb, Adjective" in that order. It should be: "Adjective, Noun, Verb"

Any insight on why this might be happening?

Comment: how do you setSpan()s?

Comment: This way:         field[y] = input.getText().toString();

        moreText = " " + "<b>" + field[y] + "</b>"
          + " ";
        
        
        Text = story.getText();
        Text = Text.replace(start, end, Html.fromHtml(moreText));
               
        storyText = Text;
        story.setText(storyText);

Comment: don't use crappy Html.fromHtml, use Spannable.setSpan() instead

Comment: do you think that is the problem? Because I have a good system set up for what I need using HTML

Comment: would that be causing my out of order array though?

Comment: the order is the same like the order you call setSpan()

Answer (score 3):

Use [`int nextSpanTransition(int start, int limit, Class kind)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#nextSpanTransition(int,%20int,%20java.lang.Class)) to iterate over your spans. This way you get the reading order.