# How to change one span type to another in Android?

Tags: android, spannablestring, spanned

I would like to take all the spans of one type in a `CharSequence` and convert them to a different type. For example, convert all the bold spans to underline spans:

[image]

How would I do that?

*(This was a problem I was facing today, and since I have solved it now, I am adding a Q&A pair here. My answer is below.)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### How to change spans from one type to another

[image]

In order change the spans, you need to do the following things

1. Get all the spans of the desired type by using `getSpans()`
2. Find the range of each span with `getSpanStart()` and `getSpanEnd()`
3. Remove the original spans with `removeSpan()`
4. Add the new span type with `setSpan()` in the same locations as the old spans

Here is the code to do that:

```
Spanned boldString = Html.fromHtml("Some <b>text</b> with <b>spans</b> in it.");

// make a spannable copy so that we can change the spans (Spanned is immutable)
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(boldString);

// get all the spans of type StyleSpan since bold is StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
StyleSpan[] boldSpans = spannableString.getSpans(0, spannableString.length(), StyleSpan.class);

// loop through each bold span one at a time
for (StyleSpan boldSpan : boldSpans) {

    // get the span range
    int start = spannableString.getSpanStart(boldSpan);
    int end = spannableString.getSpanEnd(boldSpan);

    // remove the bold span
    spannableString.removeSpan(boldSpan);

    // add an underline span in the same place
    UnderlineSpan underlineSpan = new UnderlineSpan();
    spannableString.setSpan(underlineSpan, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

### Notes

- If you want to just clear all the old spans, then use `boldString.toString()` when creating the `SpannableString`. You would use the original `boldString` to get the span ranges.

### See also

- [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953808/3681880)
- [Looping through spans in order (explains types of spans)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43270576/3681880)
- [Meaning of Span flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41949135/3681880)