# Is there any way to change the color of an already applied BackgroundColorSpan in a SpannableString?

Tags: android, background, textview, android-spannable

What I'm actually doing is I'm storing a `SpannableString` in the form of `HTML` but it has a `BackgroundColorSpan` which has an aplha channel in its color. Now I got to know (via trials) that my aplha channel of the color goes away (due to inability of `HTML`) from the text whenever I try to store it.

Now what I want to know is that is there a way I can extract all the `BackgroundColorSpan` instances in the `SpannableString` AND change their color property? All the `BackgroundColorSpan` instances are of same color I just want to add an alpha channel to their color (by changing their color) before I present the text to users.

I figured out a way to extract all the `BackgroundColorSpan` instances by using `getSpans` but i still can't find a way to change their color.

Here's the related code:

```
SpannableString spannableDescString = new SpannableString(trimTrailingWhitespace(Html.fromHtml(note.getDesc())));
BackgroundColorSpan[] highlightSpanArray = spannableDescString.getSpans(0,spannableDescString.length(),BackgroundColorSpan.class);

if(highlightSpanArray.length!=0){
    for(BackgroundColorSpan item : highlightSpanArray){
        //what should I put here to change every item's color
    }
}

desc.setText(spannableDescString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569172/how-to-change-one-span-type-to-another-in-android)

All I had to do was to delete the current span and replace it with the `BackgroundColorSpan` of the color that I required. Here's the code snippet.

```
SpannableString spannableDescString = new SpannableString(trimTrailingWhitespace(Html.fromHtml(note.getDesc())));
BackgroundColorSpan[] highlightSpanArray = spannableDescString.getSpans(0,spannableDescString.length(),BackgroundColorSpan.class);

    if(highlightSpanArray.length!=0){

         for(BackgroundColorSpan item : highlightSpanArray){
             //what should i put here to change every items color

             // get the span range
             int start = spannableDescString.getSpanStart(item);
             int end = spannableDescString.getSpanEnd(item);

             // remove the undesired span
             spannableDescString.removeSpan(item);

             // set the new span with desired color
             spannableDescString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED),start,end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }

        desc.setText(spannableDescString);
```

I simply didn't know if I could find the starting and ending of individual spans.